# Where is neo4j-server.properties on Windows?

Tags: neo4j

On Windows, where is `neo4j-server.properties` as described in this documentation?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html

I can't find it anywhere, and creating it myself in places that seem reasonable have no effect.

I'd like to be able to access the server from a remote IP other than `localhost`. Thanks.

## Update

Neo4j is installed at `C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-community.exe`

I've created the file at  `C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\conf\neo4j-server.properties`

Here's the complete contents:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

#allow any client to connect
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

However, the settings don't seem to take effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Windows search doesn't locate it for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I think I know what's going on: You installed 1.9.4 stable via the new simplified Windows Installer? If so: That seems to be a very limited 'dev' installer. It has a simple MSI, it has a simple GUI to let you select the database, and then you do everything from the web console. This is a departure from previous methods of installing on Windows. I tried it out, and I abandoned it because I need full control of the configuration. The `conf` files, normally found in a `conf` folder parallel to the `bin` folder, are not installed with this installer.

If you want the traditional installer, grab the enterprise download.

That said: I wouldn't waste time on the 1.9.x branch unless you're running in production. If you're still in dev/test, I'd go straight to 2.0 (milestone 6 is now available). You'll get Labels (reason enough to switch), updated Cypher engine, and lots of other improvements. Also: the 2.0 installer is still a traditional configuration, complete with conf folder, where you can make all the configuration changes you need to make.

**EDIT** The download link for the zip version is now back, so you can choose either the exe or zip version of installation. This means you can install 1.9.4 just like before, and have full access to all the configuration files.

**EDIT 2**  After a bit of email exchange w/someone at Neo Technology, I found out that, for this particular installer, everything needed is bundled into a single JAR file. if you look in the `bin` folder after installing, you'll see these files:

[image: Neo4j Windows installation - JAR files]

If you search the JAR file (via 7zip or something similar), you'll find the default server configuration file:

[image: Default server config]

I suspect you could place the neo4j-server.properties file into the JAR file here as well (though I haven't tried).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the suggestion about 2.0, though I had heard it was not for use in production yet. I've added detailed configuration information, but I'm still not seeing it have any effect. Ideas?

Comment: Correct - not ready for production. That's why I only suggest 2.0 if you're still in dev/test.

Comment: Updated my answer, as the link to the zip version of the installer (which has a full conf diretory) has returned.

Comment: This works for older versions, for newer ones check Dick's solution

Answer (score 16):

From the Neo4j startup window, click the "options" button bottom left.

This shows an options windows which includes the path to your conf file:

[image]

Comment: This helped me set up my Windows environment correctly. My `neo4j-server.properties` file did not exist, so I simply created it, added my settings, restarted the server and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The original poster is using the Community version on Windows, as am I.  Despite what anyone has said, no one has actually answered the question with verifiable, tested results.  I originally said, *"This is not an answer"*.  However, I now tend to think it **IS** the answer, just not the desired result.  The answer is, to the best of my knowledge, with my specific tests and results documented below: **NOWHERE: YOU CAN'T CONFIGURE** *current stable* 1.9.4 or *milestone* 2.0.0-M06 Community versions on Windows x64.

**I have tried the suggestions under the best answer, which were untested and unverified, and they do not work.**  See specific quotations below.

Neither of the currently pushed 2.0.0-M06 or stable 1.9.4 Community versions are configurable in any way, shape or form on Windows -- given the current documentation and non-answers.  As a first time user to Neo4j with these two versions, this has been very frustrating, to have no clear way to configure the software, and incorrect official documentation.

> "Also: the 2.0 installer is still a traditional configuration, complete with conf folder, where you can make all the configuration changes you need to make." @David Makagon

This is a false statement.  It is the same as 1.9.4, no conf folders anywhere on disk.

> "I suspect you could place the neo4j-server.properties file into the JAR file here as well (though I haven't tried)." @David Makagon

I have tried both Neo4j Community 1.9.4 and 2.0.0-M06 x64 on Windows 7 x64, running as a user, with and without running as administrator.

I've used ProcMon and could not even find any attempt to read any "conf" file at documented location.  However, I found other odd locations with a "config" in the name, and have tried there also, out of morbid curiosity, included below.

Summary of config file locations which **DO NOT** work:

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\conf\neo4j-default.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\conf\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4, 2.0.0-M06]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-community.exe.Config [1.9.4]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-default.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\conf\neo4j-server.properties [2.0.0-M06]
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar\org\neo4j\server\config\community\neo4j-default.properties
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar\org\neo4j\server\config\community\neo4j-server.properties
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4\org\neo4j\server\config\community\neo4j-default.properties
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4\org\neo4j\server\config\community\neo4j-server.properties
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\neo4j-default.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\conf\neo4j-default.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\conf\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\neo4j.properties [1.9.4, 2.0.0-M06]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4]
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\conf\neo4j-server.properties [1.9.4]
```

Also note, the jar's config file

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar\org\neo4j\server\config\community\neo4j-default.properties
```

corresponds directly to (exact same file, no differences)

```
C:\Users\root\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\neo4j.properties
```

Yet changing the port in this location also does nothing.

Is there a way to configure this through the webadmin?  It is definitely not clear at all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the Windows 32 community version 2.0.3. To edit any of the properties, there's "settings" button in the GUI (where you start the database from)?

Comment: Thanks.  Using 2.2.5, the button is labeled "Options...".  Maybe a change from previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

Download the windows community binary 64bit .zip from 'Other Versions'.  You'll need to install the JDK 7 and set the JAVA_HOME path variable.  All folders, including Conf, are exposed and you can control the the default port and localhost bindings per documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I spent a while on searching for it today.
The seo4j-server.properties file is at (absolute path example):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community\neo4j-server.properties
```

It is accessible from Neo4j GUI - under the "Setting" button. I have tried it with Community version 2.1.6 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Under `...\<neo4j-community-1.8.2>\conf` directory.

Comment: Can you provide an example absolute path please... is this under `%APPDATA%`? `%PROGRAMFILES%`?

Comment: @jocull this depends on where you have installed. I suggest you search for "neo4j" and go from there.

Comment: It's a completely default installation. `conf` is nowhere to be found.

Program Path: `C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin`
DB Path: `C:\Users\James\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`

Answer (score -1):

The conf file is created under AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition when you click on edit in server configuration (Options GUI)