# Where is neo4j.properties file

Tags: neo4j

This may be a simple question, but where is the `neo4j.properties` file. I want to turn auto indexing on, however when I search in the Neo4J folders (I have Neo4J community), I cannot find the properties file anywhere.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us with more details such as how you installed it and which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is neo4j-server.properties on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520507/where-is-neo4j-server-properties-on-windows)

Comment: If you installed v1.9.4 via the Windows installer, please see the question I linked to as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

By default, this will be under `${neo4j.home}/conf` if you have neo4j installed from the untar.