# Copying a local database from one computer to another ne04j

Tags: neo4j

I created a database Neo4j on a PC, with many relationships, node, etc
how to move/ copy the database from this pc to another?
thanks for the help
francesco

update1: I have tried to found conf/neo4j-server.properties but i don't have...
this is a screenshot of my folder ne04j (It is in Windows document Folder)
http://s12.postimg.org/vn4e22s3x/fold.jpg

Comment: You need to add more information to your questions, look for existing answers and stop posting Answers which are not answers. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520507/where-is-neo4j-server-properties-on-windows . As it happens that folder that you have posted a screenshot of *is* the folder that you should copy to your other machine. Make sure and look at the dump command too.

Comment: I'm moving a neo4j for third time. Still, I encounter many problems. When I copy `graph.db` folder some say authentication information is included here. BUT I JUST WANT TO MOVE DATA

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/ This is recommended way by neo4j

Answer (score 13):

Neo4J databases live in your filesystem, you can simply make a copy of the folder in which your Neo4J data is stored. If you are running standalone this folder will be configured in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and the line will look something like this:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
```

Copy the content of that folder to the graph database folder on your other machine. I'd recommend that your databases are not running when you do this.

Comment: I don't found the folder. I have folder ne04j in document folder but i don't have conf/neo4j-server.properties

Comment: why this answer is at the bottom? It worked for me but what happens if there are more than 1 DB ?

Comment: i tried to copy content of ~/.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-e668a08d-c486-4639-abad-e51a8b5f2e3d\installation-3.5.2\data\databases they were two files a folder called graph.db and other called store_lock, i copied these into the same folder of neo4j in linux, then i restarted neo4j in linux mate and worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the `dump` shell command which you can use to export a database into a single Cypher `create` statement, you'd "dump" the database and then import it on your new machine.

Information on using the command is outlined here: [Neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements)

Comment: This absolutely would work, but in general it seems not as easy as the other answer, which is just copying files off of the filesystem.  If you do it with DUMP, you later have to re-run the created cypher, which will take time for neo4j to interpret it and essentially re-create the files that you can just copy from the hard disk.

Comment: For OP -- where DUMP is *superior* to copying the database directory is when you want to do a partial dump.   I.e. if you copy the database files, you get the whole thing.  If you only want to export/copy a subgraph, DUMP is your friend.

Comment: Indeed, you're quite right. I didn't realise that copying the data files was an option.

Comment: This is clearly the correct way to do things and it is best to understand the dump command. The Neo4J backup works similarly to my answer, but if for example you wanted to seed a project database I would want a human readable, human extensible format (similar to .sql) and not a load of index files!

Answer (score 2):

A Neo4j database **can be dumped and loaded** using the following commands:

```
neo4j-admin dump --database=<database> --to=<destination-path>

neo4j-admin load --from=<archive-path> --database=<database> [--force]
```

Limitations

- The database should be shutdown before running the dump and load commands.

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/

Answer (score 0):

i used the above solution, but the file name was different.

in the folder of the `neo4j` data, look for folder called `conf` and inside the configuration file called `neo4j.conf`
inside this file you will see a line that direct to the folder that contain the data.
its called "graph.db"
replace it with the same folder from your backup of the DB that you want to clone.