# Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed for unmanaged extension

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using a custom web services as unmanaged extension for neo4j.

Here is the detail provided by neo4j that i have followed and created an unmanaged extension of my own.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

but i am getting the response as:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
}
```

I am using neo4j2.3, i have username and password of the database but i don't know where to provide the authentication details in the url to by pass this check.

here is my url http://localhost:7474/unmanaged/test/query/34553

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide authorization information as request header

```
Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6c2VjcmV0

bmVvNGo6c2VjcmV0 is default password (neo4j)
```

More information is here - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html

Or you can turn off authorization in configuration file neo4j-server.properties

```
# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Comment: i cant find **neo4j-server.properties** file in neo4j2.3.
there is no conf folder.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan How did you install Neo4j 2.3?

Comment: through .exe installer for windows

Comment: Sorry the version is 2.2.3

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan this could be helpful to find configuration file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520507/where-is-neo4j-server-properties-on-windows